# Error when get value from json_decode() in php?

Tags: php, json, object, space

I have a sample code:

```
$description = '{"2G Network":"GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900 ","3G Network":"HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1700 / 1900 / 2100 "}';
$data = json_decode($description);
echo $data->2G Network;

 // OR echo $data['2G Network'];
```

result is error, how to fix it !

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
echo $data->{'2G Network'};
```

The problem wasn't with JSON, but that you had a space in the object property you were trying to access.  If you use curly braces `{` `}`, then you can use strings to name the property you want to get/set.

Comment: Result: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 3):

Brad solution is perfect, and if you want similar from an array you can do it like:

```
$description = '{"2G Network":"GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900 ","3G Network":"HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1700 / 1900 / 2100 "}';
$data = json_decode($description, true);
echo $data['2G Network'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove the space between 2G and Network or decode the json to an array using `json_decode($description, true)`

Answer (score 0):

you may call functions to remove the spaces in the JSON

see below
http://www.pukkared.com/2010/02/removing-extra-white-space-before-returning-json-data/

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem.  The PHP JSON parser (or any valid JSON parser) doesn't care about whitespace outside of property names or string values.