# Access JSON output with spaces

Tags: php, json

If a JSON string has spaces in its name `"Some Items"` (is there a more accurate term for this?), how do you access it in PHP after using `json_decode($json_string)` on it? Is this name even required for data returned from an API?

**JSON String**

```
{"Some Items":[{"post_id":"1284"},{"post_id":"1392"},{"post_id":"1349"}]}
```

**These doesn't work**

```
$data = json_decode($json_string);
$data = $data->"Some Items";    // invalid PHP
$data = $data["Some Items"];    // Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when get value from json_decode() in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480954/error-when-get-value-from-json-decode-in-php).  Also see [example #2 in the manual for json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#example-3470).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like the curly braces idea you can use the dynamic accessor business:

```
$someitems = "Some Items";
var_dump($data->$someitems);
```

Or, you could cast $data to an array and use the square brackets:

```
$data = (array)json_decode($json_str);
var_dump($data['Some Items']);
```

`json_decode` has a switch so you don't need to use casting.

```
$data = json_decode($json_str, true);
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use curly brace (`$object->{'...'}`) syntax:

```
$data->{'Some Items'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$data->{'Some Items'};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that

```
<?php
$json = '{"Some Items":[{"post_id":"1284"},{"post_id":"1392"},{"post_id":"1349"}]}';
$decoded = json_decode($json);

// for example
echo($decoded->{"Some Items"}[0]->post_id);
?>
```