# Pulling data with spaces in json

Tags: javascript, php, json

I can't extract the data with spaces in the area that I have shown with the red pen, how can I do this?

```
        $.ajax({
        url: "../api/api.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            tc: $("#tcx").val(),
            
        },
        success: (res) => {
            if (res) {
                var json = JSON.parse(res);
             
                $('tbody').html("");
        $.each(json, function(key, value) {
            
            $('tbody').append('<tr>' +
                '<td>' + value.YAKINLIK + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.TC + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.ADI + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.SOYADI + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.DOGUM TARIHI + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.NUFUS IL + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.NUFUS ILCE + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.ANNE ADI + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.ANNE TC + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.BABA ADI + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value.BABA TC + '</td>' +
                
                '</tr>');
        });
            } else {
                alert("Hata oluştu!");
                return;
            }
        },
        error: () => {
            alert("Hata oluştu!");
        }
        
    });
}
```

I tried to parse but without success
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIKS5.png)

Comment: Please include your code that you've tried to use to parse this data.

Comment: @LawwrenceWebDev ekledim

Comment: you missed `</tr>`and change to `value["NUFUS ILCE"]`. it would work

Comment: Use brackets: [Access JSON output with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075412/access-json-output-with-spaces)

Comment: @Popeye don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to read out the value from an object, based on a key that has spaces in it, you can use this syntax:

```
const myObject = { withoutSpaces: 1, "with spaces": 2 };
const valueOne = myObject.withoutSpaces;
const valueTwo = myObject["with spaces"];
```

So in your case you want to use something like:

```
value["DOGUM TARIHI"]
```

Comment: I don't know much about Javascript. Can you translate the above code block according to the code you wrote?

Comment: Instead of `value.DOGUM TARIHI` you need to use `value["DOGUM TARIHI"]`